# Subdivision Surface Artifacts / Topology Issues?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, artifacts

I am trying to create an archway and getting this little artifact with subsurface. I've tried a few things, moving some geometry around but unable to get rid of it. Any insight as to what I need to do to fix?

[image]

Looking closer at the underlying geometry created by subsurface makes it appear that an ngon is being created at this corner.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider retopologizing it a bit (changing the edges flow). Here's my proposal:
[image]

This kind of geometry doesn't create the shading artifacts plus allows you to properly crease the subsufed mesh with edge loops.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Edge split modifier

At the moment, all the faces are shaded smooth. There are some of your quads that are stretched (you can see by applying the subsurf modifier).

[image]

Basically, smooth shading model interpolate the normal values of the vertices of the quads, but in the quad affect by the issue, two of them are at great distance and one of them is on a sharp edge.

A possible solution could be to use an Edge Split Modifier:

[image]

Comment: The only downside of this is it removes the smooth edge. looking at the subd wireframe it looks like its actually making an ngon at that corner